# why does '%d' not return the right value?

Tags: c, int

```
int a = 31; 
int b = 1; 

while (a)
{
    b = (2 * b) + 1;
    a--;
};

printf("count:%d \n", b);
```

it prints the right number when `a` is smaller than `31`. Starting from `31`, it just prints `-1` and I don't understand why. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It does now explain how to fix it :)

Comment: the problem will be obvious when you add a printf statement inside the while loop to print the calculated value of b

Comment: Nit pick: the semicolon after the `}` is a null statement and can be removed without effect. Blocks are not terminated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

The integer overflows and will become negative.

To fix this, you can change the `int` variable `b` to `long`.

```
long b = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the two's complement internal representation of type int if its size is equl to 4 bytes the sign bit is equal to 2^31.

Thus then you multiply b by two when b is equal to INT_MAX then the sign bit is set and the number is converted to -1.

That is while the sign bit is not set you get poistive numbers  1, 3, 7, 15 and so on. As soon as the sign bit is set you get negative number -1 that has internal representation with all bits including the sign bit are set.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is terminated when `a` becomes 0, since the condition

```
 while (a) ...
```

evaluating to

```
while (a != 0)...
```

It will happen after the loop is executed `31` times with the following expression in it:

```
b = (2 * b) + 1;
```

while the initial value of `b` is `1`. It will generate the series: `1, 3, 7, 15... 2^(k+1)-1`, while `k` is the iteration number (starting from 0 for initial value). So for k=`31` the value would be `2^32-1`. `2^32` is overflowing the 4-byte integer storage type, which is resulting in an undefined behavior. But some compilers are usually handling the overflow by just throwing away the overflowed leftmost bits, so the truncated `2^32` is becoming `0`. So `0-1 = -1` and this is your result. But again, no standard is guaranteeing that you will get this result, so you should never rely on it. 
To fix it, you can use a bigger storage type, like `long`, and use `%ld` for `printf`.

Comment: at the begin of the last iteration `b` is `2147483647` and so `2*b` will be undefined behaviour and can result in `-2` which will result in `b` equal `-1` after the last iteration. The program will never calculate `0-1` to get `b`.

Comment: @mch You are right. Through compilers are mostly working this way. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Unsigned integer overflow is well defined (modular arithmetic) but signed integer overflow is UB.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok the @EugeneSh. answer, but the series don't start in 1, but 3. And to print all values of b, the printf needs to stay into the while loop.If the intention were starting in 1, the printf needs to be the first line into the while loop.

Comment: If you look closer, my answer says that the series is starting from the iteration number `0`, which is for the initial value of `b`

Comment: Sorry, @EugeneSh. , I hadn't seen it.